# Read only indicator in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I have an existing Shiny script with standard widgets from the Shiny library. Now I wish to add something to show temperature on a graphical scale?  This would be a read-only value, so it wouldn't make sense to use a slider unless the slider can be locked and only changed programatically. Is that possible? If not, what are other suggestions?

---

To clarify:

Is it possible to have a Shiny slider as read only. The user can not slide it but it can be programmatically changed. Here is a Shiny slider:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  sliderInput("aa", "Temp",
              min = -20, max = 20,
              value = 10, step = 10)
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I'm not familiar with Shiny Dashboard but I saw taskItem. Can these be "dropped in" and used with a normal Shiny app that uses fluidPage, sidebarPanel, mainPanel? How does one remove the bullet point and the percentage? Here is an example of a taskItem.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    taskItem(value = temp <- 89, color = "red",
                                      "Temp"
                             ))
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

  temp <- 89

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Add it as an image?

Comment: I don't know what other help can be provided unless you provide a little more information. On SO, we prefer fully *reproducible examples*, where we can better see what you are trying to do and give you something relevant to your situation. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: See clarification.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `sliderInput` cannot be used as an output. However here's a potential solution using `progressBar` from `shinyWidgets` package

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h3("Sidebar")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      br(), br(), br(),
      progressBar("tempbar", value = 0, title = "Temperature", status = "danger")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  temp <- 89
  updateProgressBar(session, id = "tempbar", value = temp)
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[shiny app with temperature bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZv1B.png)

Replace `temp` in `server` with whatever calculated value you might have. For fixed temperature value just set it in `ui`, no need to use `updateProgressBar`. By default `progressBar` is scaled from 0-100. To modify see documentation for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `updateSliderInput` to achieve such an behaviour. Couple this with `shinyjs::disabled` and you get what you want. I would however look for a less hackish solution:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  ## add style to remove the opacity effect of disabled elements
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
                    .irs-disabled {
                       opacity: 1      
                    }")
              )
  ),
  useShinyjs(),
  disabled(sliderInput("aa", "Temp",
                       min = -20, max = 20,
                       value = 10, step = 10)),
  actionButton("Change", "Change")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$Change, {
    new_temp <- sample(seq(-20, 20, 10), 1)
    updateSliderInput(session, "aa", value = new_temp)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```